# Scala 2.13 overloaded foreachBatch

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, apache-kafka-streams, snowflake-connector

I am trying to write stream dataset to snowflake as indicated below

```
val query = expandedDF.writeStream
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("30 seconds"))
    .foreachBatch{(batchDF:DataFrame, batchID: Long) => 
    batchDF.write
        .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
        .options(sfOptions) 
        .option("dbtable", "TWITTER")
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .save()

    }
    .outputMode("update")
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

However, whenever this command is executed I run into the error

> overloaded method foreachBatch with alternatives

anyone here knows how I can resolve this?

Comment: I think something is wrong with the imports, try removing the type specifications inside your foreachBatch method, the compiler will figure it out. `.foreachBatch { (batchDF, batchId) => ...}`

Comment: this returns *missing parameter type* error @AminMal

Comment: Weird, since foreachBatch does not include type parameters (I'm using spark 3.2.0). What is your spark version? (In spark 3.2.0, the signature of foreachBatch is `def foreachBatch(function: (Dataset[Row], Long) => Unit): DatastreamWriter[T]`

Comment: I am using this *"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "3.2.1"*

Comment: What's the type of `expandedDF`?

Comment: class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

Comment: I mean it should be Dataset[Row], so if it’s something like Dataset[SomeType] then it wouldn’t work.